# About the use of Axios

Tags: javascript, php, html

Today, I used Axios to write a registered AJAX to submit JS, which can send requests normally, but I found that the backend is completely unable to accept the username and password information from the front end.
How can I fix it?Thank you.
Part of the JS code (JQuery):

```
var captcha_res_ticket = $.cookie("captcha.res.ticket");
var captcha_res_randstr = $.cookie("captcha.res.randstr");
var username = $("#inputUsername").val();
var email = $("#inputEmail").val();
var password = $("#inputPassword").val();
var repassword = $("#inputRepassword").val();
var agree_user_agreement = $("#agree_user_agreement").is(":checked");
var participate_in_the_user_experience_program = $("#participate_in_the_user_experience_program").is(":checked");
```

Axios part of the code(JS):

```
axios({
            url: '/user/user_registration/php/registration.php',
            method: 'post',
            timeout: 3000,
            data: {
                captcha_res_ticket: captcha_res_ticket,
                captcha_res_randstr: captcha_res_randstr,
                username: username,
                email: email,
                password: password
            }
        })
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Fix the backend to accept your request?

Comment: If you are using full version of jQuery it already has `$.ajax` api  which means you wouldn't need to also include axios. Where's your php sample code? And there is no mention of errors

Comment: need to share your backend code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> $_POST['captcha_res_ticket'];
> ```

You're trying to use PHP's default parsing for form data, but Axios posts JSON (not a standard form encoding) by default.

Please direct your attention to the [Axios manual](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format).

> By default, axios serializes JavaScript objects to JSON. To send data
>   in the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format instead, you can use
>   one of the following options.
>
> Browser
>
> In a browser, you can use the URLSearchParams API as follows:
>
> ```
> const params = new URLSearchParams();
> params.append('param1', 'value1');
> params.append('param2', 'value2');
> axios.post('/foo', params);
> ```

… and it continues with more information and examples.

Comment: Thank you.I have fixed this bug.